# Get MAC address before network is ready

Tags: network-interface, systemd-networkd, mac-address

I created a script to set a bunch of computer hostnames to the last 8 digits of the MAC address. The MAC address is a unique number baked into every computer, so it works well.

I created a systemd service that sets the hostname at boot before the network is up (so the network uses this new hostname):

```
# .service file
Before=network.target NetworkManager.service dhcpcd.service
```

However an unfortunate side affect of this is that the MAC address is blank before the network is up with the current way I am reading the mac address. So its a catch 22 situtation, I need the MAC address before network, and can only get the MAC address after the network is up. I would have thought since the MAC address is fixed, it would be possible to read it before the network is up?

I am using python [`from getmac import get_mac_address`](https://pypi.org/project/getmac/), but can use shell scripting too. Is there anyway to read the mac address before networking is up?

Comment: If you know the kernel module, load it then check to see if you can get the mac address.

Comment: I assume that you know the MAC address isn't really fixed. In any case, MAC addresses are available on downed interfaces so how are you writing your service? You can also use `hostnamectl` to set the host name any time after boot.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I wrote this and it seems to work before network is up (a bit crude but works):

```py
from pathlib import Path

interfaces = ['eth0', 'enp3s0', 'eno1']
for interface in interfaces:
    file = f'/sys/class/net/{interface}/address'
    if not Path(file).exists():
        continue
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        contents = f.read()
    mac = contents.strip().upper()
    return mac
```